# Game running in native monitor resolution instead of configured one

Tags: display, display-settings, screenresolution

I have a widescreen monitor (21:9, 2560x1080) and some older games (Skyrim, AC IV,.,..) don't support such a ratio very well. I have tried Flawless Widescreen but never had quite the results I expected so I'm trying something else.

I used Windows 10 display settings to artificially set my screen resolution to 1920x1080 (black bars on the sides are a sacrifice I can accept). However, when I try to launch a game in full screen, it automatically launches in native resolution.

I tried to modify some settings in Steam to launch them in 1920x1080 but nothing changes and some of my games aren't on Steam anyway

Why does the game use the native resolution and how can I fix that? If I can't how else can I make my games run in "fullscreen" (I can accept black barsbut I don't want to play in windoed mode)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the games itself. So Steam has nothing to do with it.
For Skyrim, there is a file `SkyrimPrefs.ini` (usualy located in %USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Skyrim)

Before you modify it, make a backup of it.

Open the file and find the lines that contain `bFull Screen`, `iSize W`, `iSize H`.

set `bFull Screen` to 1 - this will make it full screen

set `iSize W` to your desired width

set `iSize H` to your desired height

You can search the internet for settings like this on the internet or games forums. Usually the older games, have poor widescreen support in general.